# How to enable basic authentication in Atlantis?

Tags: terraform, terragrunt, atlantis

I'm trying to enable basic auth for `atlantis` I have followed the official docs [here](https://www.runatlantis.io/docs/security.html#enable-authentication-on-atlantis-web-server) however it seems the below settings are not honored by atlantis

```
docker run runatlantis/atlantis:v0.18.1 server --gitlab-user=username --gitlab-token=token --web-basic-auth=true --web-username=admin --web-password=password --repo-allowlist="gitlab.com/group/*"
```

When the server is running I can login without username/password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/runatlantis/atlantis/releases/tag/v0.18.2 version `v0.18.2` has fixed issue with basic auth

> fix: add back basic auth support by @Aayyush in #2008

```
docker run runatlantis/atlantis:v0.18.2 server --gitlab-user=username --gitlab-token=token --web-basic-auth=true --web-username=admin --web-password=password --repo-allowlist="gitlab.com/group/*"
```